# How to execute "Cargo build" command feature wise using features flag?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a similar kind of structure in my project. I want to build the project feature-wise. `example1/main` and `example1/test` are two features of this project.
I can not change the structure.

```
example
+----example1
¦          +-----main
¦                ¦   Cargo.toml
¦                ¦   
¦                +---src
¦                ¦ 
¦          +-----test
¦                ¦   Cargo.toml
¦                ¦   
¦                +---src
¦
¦   Cargo.toml
```

Main manifest ./Cargo.toml:

```
[profile.release]
panic = 'unwind'

[workspace]
members = [
    'example1/main',
    'example1/test',
]
```

Workspace manifest ./example1/main/Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = 'main'
version = '2.0.0'
```

When I am executing `cargo build --features main` or `cargo build --features test`, I am getting below error message

```
error: --features is not allowed in the root of a virtual workspace
note: while this was previously accepted, it didn't actually do anything
```

Can anyone please help me to fix this? Please let me know what configuration I am missing in root cargo.toml file.

Comment: instead of using `--feature` which is for cargo features, try using `-p main`. https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch14-03-cargo-workspaces.html

Comment: `--feature` is there to specify which [features](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html)s to build the project with, not which project to actually build. You can instead use the `-p` flag as Prime_Aqasix recommend, or `cd` into the respective main/ test directory and just run `cargo build` to build the project in the current working directory

Comment: @Prime_Aqasix I just updated my question. main and test are two features of this project.

Comment: @Sonu when you say "features" do you mean in relation to Rust or in a general sense? Because your project structure shows that they are two different crates.

Comment: @vallentin they are two different crates.